# Apple Developer or Enterprise with own iphones

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am kind of... well, overwhelmed by either the lack of information or too much information and I cant really find what I am looking for.

My goal is to distribute an app under my companies name to selected users within in the company. They, however, can use their own devices.

However, once I read that Enterprise allows that but then on another page I read that the used iphones must be registered for the company I am planning to release it to.

The optimal solution would be that that app isnt available on the public app store.

Is this even possible?

Comment: While technically the devices should be owned by the enterprise, Apple wont really care as long as you comply with the other requirements; ensuring that only employees use the app, distributing it via a secure web site that has a log in and so on.  Having said that, if you can, you are better off using a custom app.  This is a standard developer membership and you publish an app that is reviewed but it is only made available to specific organisation(s).  Your org must use Apple Business Manager to get the app and it is best if you have an MDM to distribute the app to devices

Comment: Hmm, ok. So I should basically use the standard developer subscription and then use Business Manager with MDM to allow the download of custom apps? @Paulw11

Comment: That is the best way.  The regular developer program costs less, has less paperwork involved and apps signed through it work forever.  Enterprise program apps need to be refreshed every 6 months and need to be able to contact Apple's servers periodically to ensure the signing certificate is still in good standing

Comment: Ok, thanks so far. Just wish the Apple Docs would be a bit more clear on that side. There is a license fee to MDM though, if I read it correctly though? Or is this irrelevant with BYOD? @Paulw11

Comment: I believe that there may be some free/open source MDM solutions but most are commercial offerings either installed on-premise or accessed as SaaS.  Best practice is you should be managing BYO devices through an MDM if you are allowing company data on them; that way the company data and apps can be removed from the device when the employee leaves

Comment: This is a good session that summarises the various distribution methods https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/304

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot here. Having developed apps only under my own name for a rather smaller scale distributing it as a company and then only limited is really wrapping my head in here. One last question here sadly as I dont really remember it from when I set it up way back: When I set up the Apple Dev Profile and want to publish the apps under the name of a company do I need the D-U-N-S number here? Reason I am asking this is we might later publish a app by ourselves: i the individual / sole proprietor the correct option or the company/organisation?

Comment: While you can use a personal membership to create custom apps (I have done so using my personal membership) if you want an app in the App Store to show that is was published by a company and not "John Smith" then you want the company/organisation membership